# Datastructure for csv data

Tags: python, python-2.7

As indata I get for example the following (CSV-file):

```
1;data;data;data
1.1;data;data;data
1.1.1;data;data;data
1.1.2;data;data;data
2;data;data;data
2.1;data;data;data
etc...
```

I have tried to use a Tree data structure:

```
def Tree():
    return collections.defaultdict(Tree)
```

But the problem is that I would like to store data as following:

```
t = Tree()
t[1][1] = [data,data,...,data]
...
t[1][1][1] = [data,data,...,data]
```

And this won't work with the data-structure defined above.

Comment: "Easy to search the data" is way to general. What do you want to search for? What should be the results? Parent/children should be easy, take a look at `string.split`.

Comment: @dtech sorry, I've updated and hope that's less general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot both store a key and children in a single dict entry:

```
tree[1] = [myData]
tree[1][5] = [myOtherData]
```

In this case, `tree[1]` would have to be both `[myData]` and `{5: [MyOtherData]}`

To work around it, you could store the data as a seperate element in the dict:

`tree = {
    1: {
          'data': [myData]
          5: {
              'data': [myOtherData]
          }
       } 
    }`

Now you can use:

```
tree[1]['data'] = [myData]
tree[1][5]['data'] = [myOtherData]
```

Or if you want, you can use another magic index like `0` (if 0 never occurs), but `'data'` is probably clearer.